# NSArray of NSDictionaries into NSDictionary of NSArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have created an NSDictionary of NSArrays based on a keyValue from the NSDictionaries found in the original NSArray. However I have an issue where the values inside the original NSDictionary are all strings but contain numbers.

The reason this is a problem is because my sorted NSMutableArray looks like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
... etc
```

the issue being is it gets sorted into the NSDictionary of arrays like this

```
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I would like to know how to keep the orginal order found in the original NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries?

This is how I am creating the NSDictionary of Arrays.

```
NSMutableDictionary *sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *dict in xmlMArray) {
    NSString *currentNumberString = [dict objectForKey:@"Number"];
    if(![[sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView allKeys] containsObject:currentNumberString])
        sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView[currentNumberString] = [NSMutableArray array];
    [sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView[currentNumberString] addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: NSDictionnary dont work with indexes, thus you cannot sort them

Comment: I don't see how converting to dictionaries will help, but using a sort which incorporates the NSNumericSearch option for NSString compares will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary is an unordered collection. You can't keep the original order (or any order) when you store things in a dictionary. For ordered collections, you want NSArray or NSOrderedSet.

Comment: I thought this is what your supposed to do to create an object to use in a sectioned UITableView?

Comment: No. An array of arrays works well for a sectioned table view, but since dictionaries are unordered, they are never useful for storing ordered contents. T(hey can be a good choice for the data you display in and individual cell however.)